# Is it possible to display html content stored in backend properly in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have couple of html documents stored in the backend mongo database. When I tried to render it with {{> pageContent}}, it showed in plain text with all html attributes. Is it possible to send it to Meteor client in such a way it can redner it as clear html?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three brackets:

```
{{{pageContent}}}
```

where `pageContent` is the raw html from your mongo database through a helper